# Extjs: Execute a function at a regular interval

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

How can I launch a function at a regular interval with ExtJS.
I tried the example code [from the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.TaskRunner-cfg-interval), but I get an error.

```
var runner = Ext.util.TaskRunner(),
task = runner.start({
     run: function(){ ... },
     interval: 1000
});
```

Error in `task = runner.start( ... )`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'start'
```

Also I find that this code is quite long. Isn't there a shorter version for launching a regular task in ExtJS ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A shorter version is

```
Ext.TaskManager.start({
  run: function() { ... },
  interval: 1000
});
```

`TaskManager` is a singleton instance of `TaskRunner` which is created automatically for you by Ext.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the `new` keyword. You have to create a *new* TaskRunner.

```
var runner = new Ext.util.TaskRunner();
```

Comment: This was too basic, sorry. But there remains the second part of the question. Isn't there a shorter way to achieve this ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I've never worked with ExtJS 4.x (only 3.x). Anyway I don't think there is a much shorter way, but you can at least create a wrapper function that takes the task's function and the interval as parameters and returns either the `runner` or the `task`, similar to [window.setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) (which you can use, too).

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of ExtJS, e.g., 3.3, "Ext.TaskMgr" is the task manager.

```
Ext.TaskMgr.start({
  run: function() { ... },
  interval: 1000
});
```